# Httpcontext current cache gets cleared

Tags: c#, caching, httpcontext

I'm storing values into `HttpContext.Current.Cache`using the `Insert`method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

In my mind this should store the value in the cache in 1440 minutes. But somehow the cache gets cleared and the key doesn´t exist anymore. The last time I checked this the cache was saved in about 30 minutes.

Could the cache be cleared somehow? If the AppPool is recycled or something like that?

Comment: Insert method will overwrite an existing cache item. you may try Add() and check where you are overwriting. The Add method will fail if you try to add value with same key.

Comment: That doesnt explain why the cache is empty for that key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the cache is stored in memory until the process is stopped and hence restarting / resetting IIS or Recycling the App Pool would clear the cache. If it is a local host, building the application will also clear the cache.

Comment: Now am I not sure that the IIS has been recycled. Are there any more possibilities?

Comment: Could it be application pool timeout? I did notice it was set to 20min be default

Comment: Yes that could also be the reason, but i wonder how it was working for 30 minutes earlier. Any idea if the application was used actively for around 15 minutes when it actually worked for 30 min?

Comment: Because i am not aware of your other environment details, i would like to suggest you to do the below to confirm. >> Set the apppool timeout to 5 min, restart your IIS, monitor if your cache exists for 5 min, then leave it idle for 10 minutes and verify it again, if expired, then this would be the reason for loosing cache data

Comment: Will try! Thanks :)

Comment: I believe the problem is within the IIS configuration. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that piece of code is executed? Setting both `AbsoulteExpiration` and `SlidingExpiration` is illegal in `Cache.Insert`. Your code should throw `ArgumentException` if executed.

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Proper usage would be

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, item, null, dateExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Use `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` if you want `AbsoluteExpiration` of 1440 minutes.

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(key, value, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1440), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it's runned. Isn't `Cache.NoSlidingExpiration` equal to `TimeSpan.Zero`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.noslidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx